# Is it possible to split a Java list into three without looping?

Tags: java, list

Given a Java List with 21 elements.

What is the best way to create three new lists with:

```
A = 0, 3, 6, ... indexed elements from source
B = 1, 4, 7, ... 
C = 2 ,5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20
```

Is it possible without looping?

Comment: Even if the abstraction you use choose does not look like a loop, the loop will occur anyway.

Comment: If it is, I'd like to know how! It would be possible if you just wanted three lists of seven (I think). But Why don't you want to loop? AND actually, can't you just hard code the indexes?

Comment: I like convenient abstractions and I'm used to functional programming. I know that a loop will need to be done eventually but I'd rather not think about it.

Comment: @Annan: "I want to abstract away the loop" and "I don't want there to be looping" are *very* different matters. You can easily write a utility method to do the looping for you, then you don't need to think about it elsewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet True! The question is badly phrased. Though I find both questions interesting! My original intention was to find if there was a built in method for doing what I wanted before making my own.

Comment: @Annan: Well, my existing answer tries to address the "no looping at all" side of things. It's not clear whether it's what you're after though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'll leave the question as it stands (without looping). I want to see if anyone else has an ingenious solution.

Comment: @Annan: If you're used to functional programming, is it something like `filter` but on an index that you want here?  Or are you actually trying to create new lists.  Because if it's filter you want, it might be easier to tackle the filtering at the `Iterator` level.

Comment: @Annan: Don't you think that using loops is part of learning a language? There is nothing wrong with using them, and in cases like this it will really complicate what should be a task if you don't use them. A loop is a function in it's own right.

Answer (score 6):

Well you *could* write a wrapper class which is able to provide a read-only "view" onto a list given a multiple (3 in this case) and an offset (0, 1 and 2). When asked for the item at a particular index, it would have to multiply by the "multiple" and add the offset, then look into the original list. (Likewise for the other operations.)

It would be simpler to loop though... what's the context here? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkPeters: I don't think `List.subList` actually does what's want here, does it? `List.subList(0, 3)` would wrap indexes 0, 1, 2 from the original list - not 0, 3, 6 as required.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that those were indices.

Comment: removes and adds will screw you over though unless it's a read-only view

Comment: @ratchetfreak: That's why I said a *read-only* view in the answer. Even if the original list is modified, the views should still be okay. Their sizes will change, of course.

Comment: not when there's an insert(0,obj) in the original list (all elements in list with offset 0 will now be in list with offset 1)

Comment: @ratchet freak: I'd think that would be the expected behavior. You're explicitly defining the result lists in terms of indices in the original.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what Jon mentioned (if of course you really don't want to just loop). The name isn't great... I'm not sure what a good name for such a thing would be.

```
public class OffsetList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

  private final List<E> delegate;
  private final int offset;
  private final int multiple;

  public static <E> OffsetList<E> create(List<E> delegate, int offset, int multiple) {
    return new OffsetList<E>(delegate, offset, multiple);
  }

  private OffsetList(List<E> delegate, int offset, int multiple) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.multiple= multiple;
  }

  @Override public E get(int index) {
    return delegate.get(offset + (index * multiple));
  }

  @Override public int size() {
    int offsetToEnd = delegate.size() - offset;
    return (int) Math.ceil(offsetToEnd / (double) multiple);
  }
}
```

Example use:

```
List<Integer> numbers = // the numbers 0 to 21 in order
List<Integer> first = OffsetList.create(numbers, 0, 3);
List<Integer> second = OffsetList.create(numbers, 1, 3);
List<Integer> third = OffsetList.create(numbers, 2, 3);

System.out.println(first); // [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
System.out.println(second); // [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
System.out.println(third); // [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
```

Creating each list is O(1) since they're views. Iterating each list is O(n) where n is the size of the actual view list, not the size of the full list it's based on. This assumes the original list is a random access list... this approach, like index-based iteration, would be very inefficient with a linked list.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Or is this just vengeance for my downvote?

Comment: You're a Guava guy.  Is there any (planned or otherwise) safe way to `filter` while being aware of the index you're filtering?  I think it works in practice because the `Predicate` is run in the order of the elements (so you can maintain an index in the `Predicate` itself) but that isn't safe since that behaviour is not documented to be true.

Comment: Of course in something like Haskell you could zip the list with an identity list, creating a pair of element to index at each index, then filter based on the index part of the pair, and then transform back to only include the first element of each pair.  Guava is missing the `zip` part of that but has `filter` and `transform` already.

Comment: @MarkPeters: I don't know of any plans for something like that, though I don't know what they're planning inside Google that hasn't been mentioned/released publicly yet. I seem to recall some discussions/issues related to index-based things like that which make me think they are not in favor of that sort of thing or don't think it's a common enough need.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at the latter.  If you need to do complex filtering by index it is probably true that you're using a poor choice of data types in the first place (i.e. you're throwing disparate things into a common list when you shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

Given you saying you're used to functional programming, I'm going to assume you want to split up the lists because you want to *do* something different to each.  If that's the case I would put the filtering logic at the `Iterator` level.

You could have a wrapping *Iterator* instead of a wrapping `List`.  It might look something like this:

```
public <T> Iterable<T> filter(final Iterable<T> allElements, final int offset, final int multiple) {
    return new Iterable<T> {
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<T> {
                int index = 0;
                Iterator<T> allElementsIt = allElements.iterator();

                public boolean hasNext() {

                    while (allElementsIt.hasNext()) { 
                       if ( isDesiredIndex(index) ) {
                           return true;
                       } else {
                           allElementsIt.next();
                           index++;
                       }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                private boolean isDesiredIndex(int index) {
                    return (index - offset) % multiple == 0;
                }

                public T next() {
                    if ( hasNext() ) {
                        return allElementsIt.next();
                    } else {
                        throw NoSuchElementException();
                    }
                }

                public void remove() {...}
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Then to use it:

```
for ( ElementType element : filter(elements, 2, 3) ) {
    //do something to every third starting with third element
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with a `List`, creating a functional view of the original `List` is considerably more efficient (for a random access list) because it doesn't require dealing with the indices you aren't interested in at all. It can just skip from one index directly to the next.

Comment: @Colin: You're right (again, for a random access list).  I think in the end I favoured `Iterator` mainly because the interface is a lot simpler to replicate :-).

Comment: Of course, `AbstractList` can be incredibly easy to implement if you don't need to implement the write methods!

Answer (score -1):

Next try :)

```
class Mod3Comparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a % 3 < b % 3 || (a % 3 == b % 3 && a < b)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a % 3 > b % 3 || (a % 3 == b % 3 && a > b)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

First sort the list taking into consideration the modulo rule, then use the `Arrays.copyOfRange` method.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Mod3Comparator());
Integer[] array = new Integer[list.size()]; 
list.toArray(array);
List<Integer> A = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 7));
List<Integer> B = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 7, 14));
...
```

Also see this [example](http://ideone.com/8CreE).

Comment: Well that's uh... creative. It's also much less efficient than just looping and unclear to boot. And while it may not use a for-loop, I don't think you can say it's not looping either.

Comment: I never said that's more or equal efficient. I would use loops. :) This is only an example for Annan.

Comment: Oh, this also only works when the value at a given index is an integer and equal to the index itself.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, I can't think of a way of doing so without pretending the arrays are lists are doing the following.

```
String[] twentyOne = new String[21];

String[] first = new String[3];
first[0] = twentyOne[0];
first[1] = twentyOne[3];
first[2] = twentyOne[6];
//  And so on

String[] second = new String[3];
second[0] = twentyOne[1];
second[1] = twentyOne[4];
second[2] = twentyOne[7];

String[] third = new String[15];
third[0] = twentyOne[2];
// You get the picture
```

I only used arrays in the example because I'm more confident with them, and know them without needing to look at something.

May I ask why you want to avoid looping?

Comment: @ColinD You suggest a way then. Until I know why the OP wants to do what they are asking I don't see why this is not a solution; if you reread the question it says "Is it possible" - my answer is no! Thanks for downvoting :( (NOT)

Comment: I'm sorry you're disappointed that I downvoted, but this is just a poor solution. It uses arrays when the question is about lists, for one thing. For another, it manually sets values at indices when it could actually use loops to do the whole thing in just a few lines. Plus, it's clearly possible as described in Jon's answer.

Comment: @Colin First you complain that my question uses a form of looping, now you are telling me that my answer would be better if I used loops! As for the arrays, as I've explained on my answer I don't use Lists very often so it would slow my down answering trying to accurately write the syntax without the IDE and it's not like Lists couldn't easily be used in place of the arrays in this case.

Comment: @Andy: He's saying that manually unrolling your loops is not preferable to using looping.  You are using compile-time looping which is just a silly workaround as it makes the programmer perform the loop.  Maybe Colin and I favour practical solutions instead of tongue-in-cheek ones.

Comment: Point accepted. Though it wasn't a preferable way to go about making it (by Colin) in my opinion. I wasn't really aware that it was a form of looping anyway and it was the easiest, simplest and quickest way I could think on doing it! Though, I would hardly call it a tongue-in-cheek solution, I too favour practical solutions and as a result I can't remember the last time I did such a thing, but for this senerio I thought it would be adequate.